# MongoDB read performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, performance-tuning

I have an ingestion process which loads data into a specific collection at a very high rate. Some of these documents have to be loaded into another system in batches of 100K . Means as soon as I find 100K documents for the given criteria I load them into another system. Go ahead with the next 100K and so on. The ingestion is running in one process (a java instance) and upload of 100K docs happen in another java instance. The find query which reads the documents one by one to prepare a set of 100K docs is really slow when the ingestion process is on.

When I switch off the ingestion process, the find query is performing fast at the rate of 500 docs per 3 seconds. While ingestion is on it drops to 500 docs in 7 - 13 seconds.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Hi Colin 't Hart - I have updated my question and deleted the comments

Comment: Hi , Is there anything pending from my end which is blocking an answer . Please let me know . I am totally new to this system . Apologize for any inconveniences causes

Comment: Are we talking of a sharded cluster or a standalone instance / replica set? Which write concern are you using? How much RAM does the machine have? Spinning disks or SSDs? Also, please post the output of `db.serverStatus()` and `db.stats()` for your database.